# How to print return value of function and resolve ld, sd "Unknown op code" error

Tags: assembly, riscv

I am trying to create a fibonacci function, but I keep getting an "unknown opcode" error for ld and sd and I'm not sure why this is, mind you, I'm completely new too assembly and this is my first project. I also am confused about how I can print the result of the fibonacci function to the console, I have tried several times to no avail. Here is my attempt in which I have written in the RISC-V version of Assembly,

```
main:
   addi x10, zero, 7 # argument 1
   jal x10, fib # calls function using argument 1 as its parameter
   add a0, x10, zero # stores x10 into a0
   li a7,  1
   ecall # prints a0 to console 

fib:
   bne x10, zero, elif
   add x10, zero, zero   
   jr ra

elif:
   addi t3, zero, 1
   bne x10, t3, else
   addi x10, zero , 1
   jr ra

else:
   addi sp, sp, -8
   sd ra, 4(sp)
   sd x10, 0(sp)
   addi x10, x10, -2
   jal, fib
   ld ra, 4(sp)
   add t4, x10, zero
   ld x10, 0(sp)
   addi x10, x10, -1
   jal, fib
   ld ra, 4(sp)
   add t5, x10, zero
   addi sp, sp, 8
   add x10, t4, t5
   jr ra
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you writing 32 or 64 bit? `ld`/`sd` are 64 bit.

Comment: The assignment says I need to write it for 64 bit hardware

Comment: So made sure you're using a 64-bit assembler, or if your assembler has options, that it's configured to assemble for rv64 not rv32.

Comment: Ok, thanks for letting me know I will try downloading another assembler

Comment: Also note that for 64 bit your stack usage is wrong.

Comment: Aside: don't use labels like `elif` and `else`. Use something more descriptive. It almost looks as though you think they are part of the language syntax. Use more comments to explain the *intention* too.

Comment: Don't mix x register numbers with friendly ones, just stick with one set of namings or the other, pref the friendly ones.

Comment: Your main program needs to inform the system of its completion (via ecall #10), orcese it will accidentally run fib agaun.

Comment: As Jester says, in 64-bit mode registers are 8 bytes wide, so take rhat into account when using stack space.

Comment: thanks for all the help just wondering how can I print the return value (x10) after the fib function is complete?

Comment: In case you didnt motice, that code already does that.

Comment: oh lol, I couldn't get anything to print so I thought it was wrong, but it seems like   some other error in my code is causing that, I will adjust my code accordingly.